# How do I extract data from dynamically populated site?

Tags: python, php, python-3.x, web-scraping

I want to extract domain data from https://www.whois.com/whois/ using this site for example to get information for domain named tinymail.com i want to use https://www.whois.com/whois/tinymail.com, if I open it in browser first then soup gives credible data otherwise no domain dtata is received (I guess it is something like site putting data on cache). I do not want to use selenium method (as it will increase time required) I have tried inspecting networking option in inspect element but saw only two updates none of them is showing any data.

Comment: Don't scrape, [use an API](https://blog.api.rakuten.net/top-domain-whois-api/).

Comment: as per @AlexHowansky. There is an API given. The alternative is using the `requests` library.

Comment: APIs are paid so I wanted to go for scraping path. I would have used python-whois library but port 43 is blocked in firewall (and I am not allowed to enable it).

Answer (score 0):

you can use requests to get data:

This retrieves data from the website in the question.

```py
import requests

url = 'https://www.whois.com/whois/'

r = requests.get(url)

if r.status_code==200:
    # page works
    print(r.text)
else:
    print('no website')
```

Here is a link for more:  https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Also, you can sign up for an `API` key to get specific data. This might be free for limited data requests.

Comment: Please see edited question.

Comment: As said at the bottom of the answer. API usually allows for a certain *limited* amount of data for free. If you wanted industrial data, then would need to pay for this. In any event, `requests` would still be more efficient than `selenium`.